# Some methods in GraphServiceClient not available Microsoft.Graph

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm attempting to simply retrieve members from an AAD security group and can't seem to get my Graph code to function and, strangely, some methods such as .Request are not available in GraphServiceClient. The code below crashes in the .GetAsync method. I'm lost as to what the issue might be.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

            string tenantId = appSettings.GetValue<string>("TenantId");
            string clientId = appSettings.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
            string clientSecret = appSettings.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");

            // using Azure.Identity;
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            var groupMembers = await graphClient
                .Groups["XXXXXXXX-72fc-456f-aefd-XXXXXXXX"]
                .Members
                .GetAsync();
```

Package references:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.11" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.11" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.0.0-preview.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.48.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.0.7-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `.Request()` before `.GetAsync()`?

Comment: That's part of the problem; the .Request method is not available and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

> You are using **preview** version '*5.0.0-preview.14*' of
> **Microsoft.Graph** package that removed `Request()` section from it while calling Graph API.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment by running same code and got below results***

I created one Console application and installed packages of **same version** as you like below:

[image]

When I ran the **same code** as you, my code also crashed at **`.GetAsync`** method as below:

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

            string tenantId = "TenantId";
            string clientId = "ClientId";
            string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

            // using Azure.Identity;
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            var groupMembers = await graphClient
                .Groups["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]
                .Members
                .GetAsync();
```

**Response:**

[image]

To find out where exactly the issue lies, you can add **`try-catch`** block in your code like below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

string tenantId = "TenantId";
string clientId = "ClientId";
string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};


var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var groupMembers = await graphClient
    .Groups["xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx"]
    .Members
    .GetAsync();
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

In my case, I missed granting consent to the added **API permissions** in the application.

To **resolve** the error, I granted consent to those permissions as below:

[image]

After selecting **Yes**, Status will be changed to Granted like below:

[image]

In your case, there is a conflict between packages as you have both  `Microsoft.Graph` and connected **service dependency** to Microsoft identity platform. As you already fixed your issue, use stable versions of `Microsoft.Graph` instead of using ***preview*** version as there are few updates still going on.

**Reference:** [msgraph-sdk-dotnet/upgrade-to-v5 - GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#removal-of-request-from-the-fluent-api)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had Microsoft.Graph package installed and also a connected service dependency to Microsoft identity platform. I uninstalled the Microsoft.Graph package and suddenly the Microsoft.Graph namespace had the methods and properties I expected. Maybe someone can explain to me this oddity.